# Google not using my title tag

Tags: magento, indexing, title

I cannot get google to utilize my page's title tag.  The title that google is currently displaying using some content that we prefer not be displayed.  I've tried reindexing in magento and webmaster tools, i've tried noodp just for the hell of it but nothing works.

The page is www.mossyoakgraphics.com/full-vehicle-kits.html
and the search result showing the incorrect title is https://www.google.com/search?q=camowrap&oq=camowrap&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i59j69i60l2j69i59.6093j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=camo+truck+wrap

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control how another website decides to index your data.